# Is the Happens-Before mechanism only hb(w, r)?

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model, jls, happens-before

I'm trying to understand the Happens Before mechanism and i can't find any source in the internet talking about happens-before relationship between a READ and subsequent WRITE. I can only read about the opposite: hb(w,r).

Anyhow reading the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) i found that:

> We say that a read r of a variable v is allowed to observe a write w
> to v if, in the happens-before partial order of the execution trace:
>
> r is not ordered before w (i.e., it is not the case that hb(r, w))

It also says:

> A set of actions A is happens-before consistent if for all reads r in A, where W(r) is the write action seen by r, it is not the case that either hb(r, W(r))

I don't understand this hb(r,w) relationship, what is that and how does it work?
What is trying to say the JLS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`hb(r, w)` describes the opposite of `hb(w, r)`. Let's start with the easier to follow `hb(w, r)` that you already seem to understand. Let me write it in my own words, so that when I explain `hb(r, w)`, you can see where it's almost exactly the same explanation:

- We have some java statement (actually, bytecode, the JMM is part of the JVMS and hence about bytecode, but, let's for argument's sake blur the lines between statements and bytecode for now). We shall call this statement 'BAR'.
- We have a second statement elsewhere, we call it 'FOO'. For one of the reasons explicitly enumerated in the JMM, for example, `BAR` is the first line in the `run()` method of a thread, and `FOO` is `t.start()`, FOO/BAR have a happens-before relationship in the JMM sense.

This means that **it must never be the case** that BAR gets to observe any state as it was before FOO modified it. In other words, if some field `x` is 5, and `FOO` is `x=10;`, then if `BAR` observes `x` being 5, then that JVM is broken.

The texts tend to talk about 'observability' because that's more accurate than the far more obvious but subtly wrong: "If `hb(FOO, BAR)`, then `BAR` is guaranteed to run after `FOO`" - because if BAR doesn't observe anything FOO does, then the JVM can completely ignore the hb relationship there and reorder at will. This seems irrelevant (if it is not possible to observe which way a thing was ordered, then who cares?), but it *is* relevant: "observe" is *also* a very specific term and it doesn't mean what the english dicionary says it means. For example, "observing" that things are happening by way of how long the CPU needs to process it is in the human/dictionary definition certainly "observing", but **not** in the JMM's definition of "observing".

For example, I don't think `System.currentTimeMillis()` is specced to be an HB/HA point (I think on most impls it ends up being one - it's a lot slower than you think, but that's an implementation detail), so if `FOO` and `BAR` both log their acts, *in theory* one can notice that `BAR` occurs before `FOO` even though `hb(FOO, BAR)` - as long as `BAR` doesn't 'observe' any fields that FOO modified, that's allowed. You'll have a hard time finding a code+JVMimpl+OS+architecture combo to actually see that happening, but you managed to find such a combo, nothing is broken - bugs you file with that as example would be closed as 'working as intended'. The JVM reserves the right to do that; it's on you to write code that is aware it can happen; if you don't - your code is broken. Probably in a way that will never actually result in a problem on your current JVM stack, but broken nonetheless.

One could argue that it is possible to witness that `BAR` occurred before `FOO` via those timestamps, i.e. that it can be 'observed', but that's not the meaning of the word "observe" that the JVM implies in this section.

### And now to flip it around

What `hb(r, w)` is about is the reverse. Given that the JVM *is* allowed to reorder `FOO` and `BAR` *even if* `hb(FOO, BAR)` is established, because the only actual guarantee the JVM makes is that `BAR` cannot **observe** state as it was before `FOO` modified any of it (i.e. BAR cannot read anything that predates FOO's writes), we get into this funky scenario:

Well, then, if we flip it around and it is in fact `FOO` (the 'before' bytecode) that writes `x = 10;` and it's the `BAR` (the 'after') code that attempts to observe (read) `x`, given that the JVM explicitly does *not* define happens-before as actually requiring that FOO runs physically before BAR, is reordering then allowed and thus a JVM may wel lreorder things so that BAR gets to observe the state of `x` as it is *after* FOO writes to it, i.e., if `BAR` reads the value of `x` as `10`, then that's fine, the JVM isn't broken?

That section about `hb(r, w)` says: **No**. Given that `x` is `5` originally and some statement modifies it to `10`, the JMM makes BOTH guarantees:

- If `x = 10;` is JMM-defined as 'happening before' a read x, the read code **cannot** observe the 5.
- If `x = 10;` is JMM-defined as 'happening after' a read x, the read code **cannot** observe the 10.
- If `x = 10;` is JMM-defined as having no HB/HA relationship to code that reads x, then the read code can observe either `5` or `10` - a JVM is allowed to do either one, depending on whatever it wants including the phase of the moon. There is no guarantee of consistency either. It is allowed to flip a coin every run if the JVM wants to. However, a JVM is *not allowed* to let the read code observe anything else. pre- state is fine, post-state is fine, but nothing else<sup>1</sup>.

---

[1] As per the spec this guarantee does not exist for `long`/`double` (you can see 'sheared' updates - the top 32 bits having been set to the new value with the bottom 32 bits still on the old, or vice versa, as per the JVM spec). However, and this is a personal injection: As far as I know, no 64-bit JVM implementation exists where you would be able to observe sheared long/double updates. 32-bit hardware still exists of course. Raspberry π's are a thing, for one.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took in writing this answer. I really appreciate it!
I still have a doubt about the hb(r,w) relationship.
The JLS states that a write to a volatile variable is in happens-before relationship with all the subsequent reads on the same variable. So i can write hb(w,r).
Anyhow is it correct to use the 'hb' notation and state something like hb(r,w) while talking about volatile variables? Can reads be in happens before relationship with writes? In JLS they use hb(r,w) notation multiple times but I cannot understand why, since there is no guarantee between these actions.

Comment: `volatile` is a bit tricky in regards to ordering. `volatile` indeed establishes HB/HA, but it's hard to know what the FOO and the BAR is - if thread A interacts with field `volatile int x;` and thread B also does so, alright some HB-HA is happening here, but which one is the 'before' and which one is the 'after'? With volatile it's usually difficult to tell. `volatile` is more about 'you cant have 2 threads each plowing on with their own locally cached copy if that's a `volatile` variable - one of em will 'get' the updates of the other. Which one? Who knows - `volatile` doesn't let you order.

Comment: Point is, if thread A writes to a volatile field and thread B reads it, no, you __cannot__ say that therefore HB(A, B). Because volatile does not establish an order. Merely that an ordering will exist - one of them is hb relative to the other one, without knowing which one. Maybe ask your actual question. What _actual situation_ did you run into where you don't know if the code you wrote is JMM-safe and/or you ran into a scenario you thought couldn't happen.

Comment: @Unearthly I don’t understand what you mean with “since there is no guarantee between these actions”. The whole point of the JMM is to tell your that there are guarantees for a volatile write and subsequent volatile reads of the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand the Happens Before mechanism and i can't find any source in the internet talking about happens-before relationship between a READ and subsequent WRITE. I can only read about the opposite: hb(w,r).

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) has this text:

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - There is a happens-before edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).
> - If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

So, for example, if in the same thread READ is followed by WRITE, then hb(READ, WRITE).

---

> I don't understand this hb(r,w) relationship, what is that and how does it work? What is trying to say the JLS?

In short: JMM is rules for multi-threading programs for what a read can return.

In single-threaded code a read always returns the value written by the latest write to that variable.
In multi-threaded code things get hairy: JMM allows a read to return any value written to that variable by any write from other threads. More than that, JMM allows a read to return a value written by a write from another thread, even if that write happens later in real time than the read.
Happens-before limits the writes that a read can return: for every HB chain only that last write can be returned.

Why JMM is so relaxed:

1. it reflects the behavior of current CPUs: ARM and Power are themselves pretty relaxed
2. it allows for the compiler optimizations (compilers for single threaded programs often achieve high performance by various instruction reordering)

If the JMM were strict (e.g. like SC), then there would a huge performance loss: both in multi-threaded and single-threaded code (because many compiler optimizations for single-threaded coded would be illegal).